# Can't reach memory allocated by realloc

Tags: c, pointers, struct, memory-management, realloc

I have a global dynamic array of pointers (`iterator`) pointing to structs (`person_t`). First I malloced `10*sizeof(person_t*)` memory for the `iterator` and inside I malloced `sizeof(person_t)` memory to every `iterator[i]` `i = 0..9`.

```
typedef struct Person
{
    char name[30];
    unsigned age;
    char job[30];
} person_t;

person_t **iterator;
int size = 10;
int count = 0;

int main()
{
    int i;
    iterator = malloc(size * sizeof(person_t *));
    if (iterator == NULL)
    {
        /*fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation did not succeed\n");*/
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        iterator[i] = malloc(sizeof(person_t));
        if (iterator[i] == NULL)
        {
            /*fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation did not succeed\n");*/
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works fine until I reach the maximum capacity. When that happens, I try to realloc the `iterator` to have more memory, but it doesn't seem to work, although I don't get any kind of warnings or errors compiling (I compile with `gcc -ansi -pedantic -W -Wall -Wextra`), and realloc doesn't return NULL. This is where it all happens:

```
void grow()
{
    int i;
    size += 5;
    iterator = realloc(iterator, size);
    if (iterator == NULL)
    {
        /*fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation did not succeed\n");*/
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("realloced to bigger\n");
    for (i = size - 5; i < size; ++i)
    {
        iterator[i] = malloc(sizeof(person_t));
        if (iterator[i] == NULL)
        {
            /*fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation did not succeed\n");*/
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}
```

When I try to list my data before `grow()` is called, everything is perfectly fine. After `grow()` maybe the first 3 structs are printed (with the first one being messed up), and then I get `Segmentation fault`.

If it helps here is the full code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct Person
{
    char name[30];
    unsigned age;
    char job[30];
} person_t;

person_t **iterator;
int size = 10;
int count = 0;

void newPerson();
void grow();
void list();
void del();

int main()
{
    int i;
    iterator = malloc(size * sizeof(person_t *));
    if (iterator == NULL)
    {
        /*fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation did not succeed\n");*/
        exit(1);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
    {
        iterator[i] = malloc(sizeof(person_t));
        if (iterator[i] == NULL)
        {
            /*fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation did not succeed\n");*/
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    while (1)
    {
        char menuChoice = ' ';
        scanf("%c", &menuChoice);

        switch (menuChoice)
        {
        case 'a':
            newPerson();
            break;
        case 'l':
            list();
            break;
        case 'x':
            for (i = 0; i < size; ++i)
            {
                free(iterator[i]);
            }
            free(iterator);
            exit(0);
        case 'd':
            del();
            break;
        case '\n':
            break;
        default:
            fprintf(stderr, "\'a\' -add, \'l\' -list, \'d\' -delete,  \'x\' -exit\nOnly these inputs are allowed\n");
            break;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

void newPerson()
{
    unsigned a = 0;
    char strN[30];
    char strJ[30];
    int err;

    if (count == size)
        grow();

    /*printf("Name: ");*/
    scanf("%s", strN);
    if ((strlen(strN) + 1) > 30)
    {
        do
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Maximum 30 characters are allowed\n");
            scanf("%s", strN);
        } while ((strlen(strN) + 1) > 30);
    }
    /*printf("Age: ");*/
    err = scanf("%u", &a);
    if (err != 1)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("Only numbers are allowed\n");
            fgetc(stdin);
            err = scanf("%u", &a);
        } while (err != 1);
    }
    /*printf("Job: ");*/
    scanf("%s", strJ);
    if ((strlen(strJ) + 1) > 30)
    {
        do
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Maximum 30 characters are allowed\n");
            scanf("%s", strJ);
        } while ((strlen(strJ) + 1) > 30);
    }

    iterator[count]->age = a;
    strcpy(iterator[count]->name, strN);
    strcpy(iterator[count]->job, strJ);
    count++;
}

void list()
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        printf("%d. person:\tname: %s, age: %d, job: %s\n", i + 1, iterator[i]->name, iterator[i]->age, iterator[i]->job);
    }
}

void grow()
{
    int i;
    size += 5;
    iterator = realloc(iterator, size);
    if (iterator == NULL)
    {
        /*fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation did not succeed\n");*/
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("realloced to bigger\n");
    for (i = size - 5; i < size; ++i)
    {
        iterator[i] = malloc(sizeof(person_t));
        if (iterator[i] == NULL)
        {
            /*fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation did not succeed\n");*/
            exit(1);
        }
    }
}

void del()
{
    char toDelete[30];
    int i;
    int toDeleteIndex;
    scanf("%s", toDelete);
    if ((strlen(toDelete) + 1) > 30)
    {
        do
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Maximum 30 characters are allowed\n");
            scanf("%s", toDelete);
        } while ((strlen(toDelete) + 1) > 30);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    {
        if (strcmp(iterator[i]->name, toDelete) == 0)
        {
            toDeleteIndex = i;
        }
    }
    if (i == count)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "No match\nBack to menu\n");
    }
    else
    {
        free(iterator[toDeleteIndex]);
        for (i = toDeleteIndex; i < count - 1; ++i)
        {
            iterator[i] = iterator[i + 1];
        }
        free(iterator[count]);
        count--;

        if (count == size - 6)
        {
            size -= 5;
            iterator = realloc(iterator, size);
            if (iterator == NULL)
            {
                /*fprintf(stderr, "Memory allocation did not succeed\n");*/
                exit(1);
            }
            printf("realloced to smaller\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just as in the `malloc`, you need to specify the size in bytes.  eg:

```
v = realloc(iterator, size * sizeof *iterator);
if( v != NULL ){
    iterator = v;
}
```

This is a common error, and might be a good reason to choose a name other than "size".  (Perhaps call it "capacity").
Note that although in your code it is okay to do `iterator = realloc(iterator, size * sizeof *iterator)` since you immediately abort the program if realloc returns NULL, I modified the code to use a different variable just to emphasize that code pattern for future readers.

Comment: Thank you very much, I could have known that